# ListBox.SelectedItem is not a collection type

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to move multi Items from ListBox1 to ListBox2, but I receive an error message that the below underlined is not a collection type.

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection

For Each selectedItem In ListBox1.SelectedItem
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

To check selected items in a listbox, you need to iterate each item and write a condition that asks if the current item is selected or not.

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
    If item.selected Then
       ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
       ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
    End If 
Next
```

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.Items` returns a collection of items in the control, each `Item` has `Selected` property which returns a boolean value.

**For Windows Form Applications**: //Edit  [OP is using `System.Web.UI.WebControls`
 
`SelectedItem` will return only single item. 
`SelectedItems` will return a collection type based on selected items 
Make sure that the `SelectionMode` is not `One` or `None` 
so instead of using `SelectedItem` try to use `SelectedItems`

Comment: SelectedItems returns another error that it is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox!

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you are using it from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` I'll revise my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
For Each selectedItem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
    ListBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(selectedItem)
Next
```

The ForEach statement needs to apply to a list, so you can retrieve individual items in 'selectedItem' variable. Then you can add/remove that individual item as you like

Comment: So how I can move many items from listbox to another with one click?

Comment: He is using `System.Web.UI.WebControls` not `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: If you have your listbox defined with [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) defined as 'Multiple' you will be able to select more than one, which inside the foreach all of your selected ítems will be added to listbox2 and removed from listbox1